# Does Convenience Init need to have same number of parameters as Required Init

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

From: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html

> Create convenience initializers whenever a shortcut to a common
> initialization pattern will save time or make initialization of the
> class clearer in intent.

My understanding of convenience init is basically as a shortcut to "typical" input parameters. Most of the time, the number of parameters in `convenience init()` is the same as `required init()`

eg:

```
public required init() {
    super.init()
    
    self.$timeStamp.owner = self
    self.$position = self
    self.$distance = self
}

public convenience init(timeStamp: FitTime? = nil,
                        position: Position? = nil,
                        distance: Measurement<UnitLength>? = nil {
    self.init()
    
    self.timeStamp = timeStamp
    self.position = position
    self.distance = distance
    }
}
```

I believe there are instances where `convenience init` will have lesser # of parameters vs `required init` as some default values will be put in place.

I think the below is valid? There is an additional parameter in `required init` but is not present in `convenience init`. However, in this case, how am I able to access and pass a value to the `speed` parameter?

```
public required init() {
    super.init()
    
    self.$timeStamp.owner = self
    self.$position = self
    self.$distance = self
    self.$speed = self // ADDED THIS
}

public convenience init(timeStamp: FitTime? = nil,
                        position: Position? = nil,
                        distance: Measurement<UnitLength>? = nil {
    self.init()
    
    self.timeStamp = timeStamp
    self.position = position
    self.distance = distance
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? You have already come to the correct conclusion that a convenience init can have different parameters than the required init.

Comment: I want to be able to access the speed parameter which is not within the ```convenience init ``` method. But I can't seem to access it or rather I don't know how to. I will be able to pass a value to the speed parameter if I changed the pod's convenience method to also have the speed parameter inside. (essentially make convenience init have the same # of parameters as required init)

Comment: You can access anything from within any init that is part of the class/struct. Did you try?

Comment: I tried various methods (that I know of), but the only one that worked for me was adding the speed parameter into the convenience init. eg: I tried ```let p = RecordMessage(); p.leftRightBalance = 44``` (this resulted in an error that says ```cannot assign property: leftRightBalance setter is inaccessible)```

Comment: Then that is done for a reason so either you can not set that property at all or there exist a specific function for updating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no correlation in number of parameters between designated (or even required) initializers and convenience initializers.

Convenience initializers are simply those that need to forward initialization to one of designated initializers. How many input parameters will it have is completely dependent on implementation and use-case. It may be more, less or equal.

It is hard to find a simple-enough example to demonstrate all of those but consider something like this:

```
class HighlightedWordContainer {
    
    let words: [String]
    var highlightedWord: String
    
    init(words: [String], highlighted: String) {
        self.words = words
        self.highlightedWord = highlighted
    }
    
    init(words: [String], highlightedIndex: Int) {
        self.words = words
        self.highlightedWord = words[highlightedIndex]
    }
    
    convenience init(singleWord: String) {
        self.init(words: [singleWord], highlighted: singleWord)
    }
    
    convenience init(word1: String, word2: String, word3: String, highlighted: String) {
        self.init(words: [word1, word2, word3], highlighted: highlighted)
    }
    
    convenience init(wordsSeparatedByWhitespace: String, highlightedIndex: Int) {
        let words = wordsSeparatedByWhitespace.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)
        self.init(words: words, highlightedIndex: highlightedIndex)
    }
    
    convenience init?(descriptor: [String: Any], keys: [String], selectedKey: String) {
        let words: [String] = keys.compactMap { descriptor[$0] as? String }
        guard words.isEmpty == false else { return nil }
        
        guard let selectedWord = descriptor[selectedKey] as? String else { return nil }
        guard let selectedWordIndex = words.firstIndex(of: selectedWord) else { return nil }
        
        self.init(words: words, highlightedIndex: selectedWordIndex)
    }
    
}
```

Here I created a class with 2 designated initializers. These two need to set all properties that are not already set by default. Which means they need to set both `words` and `highlightedWord`. A designated initializer may not delegate a call to another designated initializer so the following will not work:

```
init(words: [String], highlightedIndex: Int) {
    self.init(words: words, highlighted: words[highlightedIndex])
}
```

And all convenience initializers do need to call any of the designated initializers and may also not directly set or use `self` properties UNTIL a designated constructor is being called. So:

```
convenience init(wordsSeparatedByWhitespace: String, highlightedIndex: Int) {
    let words = wordsSeparatedByWhitespace.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)
    // print(highlightedWord) // NOT OK!
    self.init(words: words, highlightedIndex: highlightedIndex)
    print(highlightedWord)
}
```

And from the example I hope it makes clear that a convenience initializer can have more, fewer or same number of input parameters. It all just depends.

Some more plausible examples:

```
class Point {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
    
    init(x: Int, y: Int) { self.x = x; self.y = y }
    convenience init(x: Int) { self.init(x: x, y: 0) }
    convenience init(y: Int) { self.init(x: 0, y: y) }
    convenience init(polar: (radius: Double, angle: Double)) { self.init(x: Int(cos(polar.angle)*polar.radius), y: Int(sin(polar.angle)*polar.radius)) }
}

class NumericValueAsString {       
    let stringValue: String // A value represented as "123.456"
    
    init(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
    convenience init(value: Int) { self.init(stringValue: .init(value)) }
    convenience init(integerPart: String, fractionPart: String) { self.init(stringValue: integerPart + "." + fractionPart) }  
}
```

Also; `required` keyword has nothing to do with anything in this context. You can place it to any of the initializers (designated or convenience), to multiple of them or even all of them.

**Adding additional info based on a comment:**

> your examples shows that you can have a convenience init that can pass
> parameters back to the required init``. what about instances where I
> there is no convenience init``` that can pass a value to parameter to
> one which is in required init but not in the convenience init. Like my
> speed parameter in my original question.

This really depends on the interface of your class which is not fully shown in your example. For instance, is `speed` publicly exposed?

If speed is public then what you are looking for is something along the lines

```
let itemInstance = MyItem()
itemInstance.timeStamp = timeStamp
itemInstance.position = position
itemInstance.distance = distance
itemInstance.speed = speed
```

or

```
let itemInstance = MyItem(timeStamp: timeStamp, position: position, distance: distance)
itemInstance.speed = speed
```

or even create a new convenience constructor

```
extension MyItem {
    convenience init(timeStamp: FitTime? = nil,
                     position: Position? = nil,
                     distance: Measurement<UnitLength>? = nil
                     speed: Speed? = nil
                     ) {
        self.init(timeStamp: timeStamp, position: position, distance: distance)
        self.speed = speed
    }
}

let itemInstance = MyItem(timeStamp: timeStamp, position: position, distance: distance, speed: speed)
```

But if your `speed` property is privately defined than you can not assign to it anywhere but internally. You need to be able to modify your class so that it can accept this property somewhere. Either via constructor, via property or via a method. Until there is no access at all you can not expect to be able to modify it.

But if this is your own class I would turn things upside down if possible. Your main constructor should be the one that accepts all 4 parameters. But your convenience initializer should be required (Yes, convenience initializer may be required). So in that case you would have:

```
public required convenience init() {
    self.init(timeStamp: self, position: self, distance: self, speed: self)
}

public init(timeStamp: FitTime? = nil,
                        position: Position? = nil,
                        distance: Measurement<UnitLength>? = nil,
                        speed: Speed?) {
    super.init()
    
    self.timeStamp = timeStamp
    self.position = position
    self.distance = distance
    self.speed = speed
    }
}
```

This specific case feels like it is missing something compared to your code but again, you did not provide full definition of your class and with it does or is supposed to do. For instance in the code you provided if one would call a convenience initializer then the following lines would execute in this order:

```
self.$timeStamp.owner = self // from self.init()
self.timeStamp = timeStamp
```

which looks like a problem to begin with.

So to wrap it up. There are very many ways you can achieve what you are asking for. But it all depends on what you are trying to build here.

I hope it at least puts you in the right track.

Comment: coming back to this.. all your examples shows that you can have a ```convenience init``` that can pass parameters back to the ```required init``. what about instances where I there is no ```convenience init``` that can pass a value to parameter to one which is in ```required init``` but not in the ```convenience init```. Like my ```speed``` parameter in my original question.

Comment: @app4g Try the edited answer please. I added a new section at the bottom.

Comment: This is great explanation. Truly Appreciated. I reviewed the class again (it's pod from https://github.com/FitnessKit/FitDataProtocol/blob/master/Sources/FitDataProtocol/Messages/RecordMessage.swift) and the ```speed``` parameter is defined as a ```private var``` now I get why I can't access it via ```itemInstance.speed = speed``` for example. I also confirmed w/ the pod developer that it was an oversight to have omitted those parameters from the ```convenience init``` and now coupled w/ your answer - I understand why that was the case.